# Pinia -vuejs: storeToRefs getters work in dev but not in production

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I am creating a SPA with vue3 and quasar. I use Laravel 10 as backend to access the database.

My getters when used as storeToRefs do not work in production although they work in dev.
By work I mean return a correct value.

I use several stores and complex getters that often work using data from more than one store.
To explain what happen, here is a simplified example (i.e. with a rather simple getter ) that illustrates  the  issue:

This is the activity store

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParticipationStore } from "./participation";
import { useCommonStore } from './common'
export const useActivityStore = defineStore("activity", {
  state: () => ({
    activities: [],
    currentEventActivities: [], //the activities of the current event
    activityErrors: [],
  }),

  getters: {

    getCurrentEventActivities: (state) => {
      return (eventId) =>
        state.activities.filter(function (a) {
          return a.event_id === eventId;
        });
    },
```

and here is the component code

Code in script

```
import { useActivityStore } from "../stores/activity";
const activityStore = useActivityStore();

const { getCurrentEventActivities } = storeToRefs(useActivityStore());
```

code in template

```
<div v-for="(activity, index) in activityStore.activities" :key="index" >
    {{ activity }}
</div>
<hr />
<div>
    The selected event Id {{ selectedEventId }}
</div>
<div class="bg-blue-2">
    <div>The selected activities using storeToRefs</div>
    <div v-for="(activity, index) in getCurrentEventActivities(selectedEventId)" :key="index">
        {{ activity }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are what I get on the screen

In development

[image]

In production
[image]

I must add that both are using the same database.
As you can see, the first part shows all the activities. As for the second part its shows the activities whose event_id is 3 in dev but nothing at all in production.

I have no idea of what to do.

Comment: What does *"do not work"* mean? Be precise. Are they throwing errors, are they giving unexpected results? Are you sure the input data is the same in both environments? It is quite rare for a store to change behavior based on environment. There's a much higher probability you're feeding that store wrong data in prod. Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve] on codesandbox.io or similar, showcasing the problem. Without one, your chances of getting help are very slim.

Comment: Thank you for your care. By "do not work" I mean " return nothing". Apparently there is no errors. To show what happens I reformulated my initial post using a very simple getter and presented picture of how is the component's view on the screen in both situations.

Comment: In your dev environment, all the event_id values are numbers, e.g. `"event_id": 3`.  In production, all the event_id values are strings, e.g. `"event_id": "3"`.  Other number columns have a similar issue.  Since you use strict equality `===` the value `"3"` does not equal `3`.  It's not clear why this is different between environments but it seems some other code or configuration not shown may be responsible. One possible workaround would be to use loose equality `==` or otherwise coerce values before comparing.

Comment: Well spotted, @yoduh. While I agree this is, most likely what's causing the difference, using non-strict equality should be avoided. A much better solution is to fix the data in prod, either by figuring out why the types are different or, if that's not feasible, by writing a function which transforms the data into the correct format.

Comment: @yoduh and tao  thank you for your help. I will try this as soon as possible.

Comment: At first glance it seems the difference exists in the response by the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As yoduh and toa pointed it, the trouble came from the backend returning different types in dev and prod.
Could be a problem of server configuration. A found a workaround in adding a  $casts array in my models e.g.

```
protected $casts=[
        'id' => 'integer',
        'event_id'=>'integer',
        'memberPrice' =>'float',
        'otherPrice' =>'float',
        'memberEntryFee'=>'float',
        'otherEntryFee'=>'float'
    ];
```